# Remove all characters except alphanumeric and spaces with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I like the solution povided by "[Remove not alphanumeric characters from string. Having trouble with the [\] character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364400/remove-not-alphanumeric-characters-from-string-having-trouble-with-the-char)" but how would I do this while leaving the spaces in place?

I need to tokenize string based on the spaces after it has been cleaned.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
input.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')
```

Shamelessly stolen from the other answer.  `^` in the character class means "not."  So this is "not" `\w` (equivalent to `\W`) and not `\s`, which is space characters (spaces, tabs, etc.)  You can just use the literal  if you need.

Comment: That works except for special characters like the slanted quotes ’ ” “.

Comment: What do you mean?  Do you want to include those characters or to exclude them?

Comment: Not completely. Normal ascii quotes work but when copying an pasting text from a PDF the angled quotes don't get removed while regular quotes do.

Comment: I really don't know what to say .. I can't reproduce this problem

Comment: `[^\w]` = `\W` and `[^\s]` = `\S` thus the regex could be reduced to `/[\W\S]/g`, the ignore case modifier isn't needed because `\W` takes these into account.

Comment: International characters also removed like ş and ö

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old thread, but so popular that appears at the top of a Google search. So, as an alternative, the accepted answer and comment from 3limin4t0r inspired me to:

```
.replace(/\W+/g, " ")
```

IMHO

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const output = document.querySelector("output");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    output.textContent = input.value.replace(/\W+/g, " ");
})
```

```html
<input>
<button>Replace</button>
<p>
  <output></output>
</p>
```