# Using regexp replace in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I use replace regex in JavaScript to get rid of everything that's not a letter, number or space in a sentence?

```
var string = "here is a sentence with letters and numbers and symbols 123!@#";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all characters except alphanumeric and spaces with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640486/remove-all-characters-except-alphanumeric-and-spaces-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var string = "here is a sentence with letters and numbers and symbols 123!@#";

var x = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g,'')
console.log(x)
```