# Javascript - How filter String ? (valid chars must be between [A..Z] or [a..z] or [0..9] )

Tags: javascript, string

What have I do to filter a String ?

I found algorithms to remove special chars, but I have to set all "invalid" chars. I don't wanna set it, I just wanna accept chars between [A..Z] or [a..z] or [0..9].

Thank you

Comment: Simple RegExp & done.

Comment: So use a regular expression.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9364527/2098269

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var invalidCharsExpression = /[^0-9a-zA-Z]/;

if(invalidCharsExpression.test(somestring))
{
  // has invalid characters!
}
```