# Using regular expression in replace method in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like `%B~7566952`, and I want a regular expression that can be applied to replace it to get `B7566952`, so a regular expression that takes non-alphanumeric characters and deletes them.

Comment: The first paragraph of http://stackoverflow.com/a/9364527/2102532 does what you need, this should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "%B~7566952";
document.write(str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, ""));
```

Comment: `str.replace(/\W/g, '')` is equivalent (well nearly, as the underscore character is in `W` but not in your expression)