# JavaScript filter similar strings

Tags: javascript

Context: I'm offering a frontend for a large list using an HTML table. The content of the table is in various different (Indo-European) languages. I want to allow my users to easily filter the table.

What's an easy / the easiest way to implement a "find similar" search? With "find similar" I mean:

- Neglect any puncation (e.g, finds `h-ell.o` when searching for  `hello`)
- Neglect homoglyphs (e.g, finds `hélló` when searching for `hello`)
- ...possibly more & vice-versa.

I already have JQuery, however, would also install a 3rd-party JS library if suitable.

Examples:

`[ 'hello', 'héllo', 'h-ello', 'hallo', 'hellot', 'hell', 'hellø' ]`

User search for `héllo`, should match `[ 'héllo', 'hello', 'h-ello', 'hellø']`
Should not match `'hallo'` (spelling only, a is not at all "connected" to an e). Shuld not match `hellot` (too long). Should not match `hell` (too short).

Comment: Try making a simple search where if a person manages to get "most" of the word in a common/European language correctly, it just displays it.

Basically I am trying to say that you should play with the string length and if you have match of 3 or higher, it should return the result. Due to the fact that most European languages have similar consonants.

Comment: I guess that could be an alternative solution, however, I'd prefer a different one. Thank you anyways!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=levenshtein+javascript

Comment: Levenshtein is a suitable solution to overcome spelling errors. Not what I'm looking for. I guess a solution to my problem would somehow use the character's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property properties to compare strings.

Comment: Can you share more cases? what is the user searches for hel-lo?

Comment: You are "looking for a straightforward library solution" but "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"[*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Netham: I've provided some examples. My biggest problem is to find a name for the "connection" between `e`, `é`, etc. Are those homoglyphs? What are those? I guess if I know the name one gives such "connections", I can build something myself.

Comment: The behavior you describe is a combination of tokenization, pattern replacement and ASCII folding.  Personally I would recommend http://lunrjs.com/ for this type of work.  EDIT: lunr doesnt offer ASCII folding, but this does: https://github.com/mplatt/fold-to-ascii

Comment: @noppa: I guess, it's not one of those "what's the best library for xyz". I', not especially looking for a library, I will gladly accept other solutions to my problem as well.

Comment: Are you using jquery table search?

Comment: I think this is pretty much what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18391901/4258088

Comment: i would use Levenshtein distance algo..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want can be described in steps as

- Remove diacritics from the searched string, which is done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18391901/2346893)
- Remove non-alphanumeric characters from the searched string, done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9364527/2346893)
- Compare the searched string and user input, ignoring case optionally

The complete code is below. The function you need is `searchOccurences`.

```js
var defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap = [{
  'base': 'A',
  'letters': '\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F'
}, {
  'base': 'AA',
  'letters': '\uA732'
}, {
  'base': 'AE',
  'letters': '\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2'
}, {
  'base': 'AO',
  'letters': '\uA734'
}, {
  'base': 'AU',
  'letters': '\uA736'
}, {
  'base': 'AV',
  'letters': '\uA738\uA73A'
}, {
  'base': 'AY',
  'letters': '\uA73C'
}, {
  'base': 'B',
  'letters': '\u0042\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0182\u0181'
}, {
  'base': 'C',
  'letters': '\u0043\u24B8\uFF23\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u00C7\u1E08\u0187\u023B\uA73E'
}, {
  'base': 'D',
  'letters': '\u0044\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018B\u018A\u0189\uA779'
}, {
  'base': 'DZ',
  'letters': '\u01F1\u01C4'
}, {
  'base': 'Dz',
  'letters': '\u01F2\u01C5'
}, {
  'base': 'E',
  'letters': '\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E'
}, {
  'base': 'F',
  'letters': '\u0046\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B'
}, {
  'base': 'G',
  'letters': '\u0047\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E'
}, {
  'base': 'H',
  'letters': '\u0048\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D'
}, {
  'base': 'I',
  'letters': '\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197'
}, {
  'base': 'J',
  'letters': '\u004A\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248'
}, {
  'base': 'K',
  'letters': '\u004B\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2'
}, {
  'base': 'L',
  'letters': '\u004C\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780'
}, {
  'base': 'LJ',
  'letters': '\u01C7'
}, {
  'base': 'Lj',
  'letters': '\u01C8'
}, {
  'base': 'M',
  'letters': '\u004D\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C'
}, {
  'base': 'N',
  'letters': '\u004E\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u00D1\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u0220\u019D\uA790\uA7A4'
}, {
  'base': 'NJ',
  'letters': '\u01CA'
}, {
  'base': 'Nj',
  'letters': '\u01CB'
}, {
  'base': 'O',
  'letters': '\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C'
}, {
  'base': 'OI',
  'letters': '\u01A2'
}, {
  'base': 'OO',
  'letters': '\uA74E'
}, {
  'base': 'OU',
  'letters': '\u0222'
}, {
  'base': 'OE',
  'letters': '\u008C\u0152'
}, {
  'base': 'oe',
  'letters': '\u009C\u0153'
}, {
  'base': 'P',
  'letters': '\u0050\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754'
}, {
  'base': 'Q',
  'letters': '\u0051\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A'
}, {
  'base': 'R',
  'letters': '\u0052\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782'
}, {
  'base': 'S',
  'letters': '\u0053\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784'
}, {
  'base': 'T',
  'letters': '\u0054\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786'
}, {
  'base': 'TZ',
  'letters': '\uA728'
}, {
  'base': 'U',
  'letters': '\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244'
}, {
  'base': 'V',
  'letters': '\u0056\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245'
}, {
  'base': 'VY',
  'letters': '\uA760'
}, {
  'base': 'W',
  'letters': '\u0057\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72'
}, {
  'base': 'X',
  'letters': '\u0058\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C'
}, {
  'base': 'Y',
  'letters': '\u0059\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u00DD\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE'
}, {
  'base': 'Z',
  'letters': '\u005A\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762'
}, {
  'base': 'a',
  'letters': '\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250'
}, {
  'base': 'aa',
  'letters': '\uA733'
}, {
  'base': 'ae',
  'letters': '\u00E6\u01FD\u01E3'
}, {
  'base': 'ao',
  'letters': '\uA735'
}, {
  'base': 'au',
  'letters': '\uA737'
}, {
  'base': 'av',
  'letters': '\uA739\uA73B'
}, {
  'base': 'ay',
  'letters': '\uA73D'
}, {
  'base': 'b',
  'letters': '\u0062\u24D1\uFF42\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u0180\u0183\u0253'
}, {
  'base': 'c',
  'letters': '\u0063\u24D2\uFF43\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u00E7\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184'
}, {
  'base': 'd',
  'letters': '\u0064\u24D3\uFF44\u1E0B\u010F\u1E0D\u1E11\u1E13\u1E0F\u0111\u018C\u0256\u0257\uA77A'
}, {
  'base': 'dz',
  'letters': '\u01F3\u01C6'
}, {
  'base': 'e',
  'letters': '\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD'
}, {
  'base': 'f',
  'letters': '\u0066\u24D5\uFF46\u1E1F\u0192\uA77C'
}, {
  'base': 'g',
  'letters': '\u0067\u24D6\uFF47\u01F5\u011D\u1E21\u011F\u0121\u01E7\u0123\u01E5\u0260\uA7A1\u1D79\uA77F'
}, {
  'base': 'h',
  'letters': '\u0068\u24D7\uFF48\u0125\u1E23\u1E27\u021F\u1E25\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E96\u0127\u2C68\u2C76\u0265'
}, {
  'base': 'hv',
  'letters': '\u0195'
}, {
  'base': 'i',
  'letters': '\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131'
}, {
  'base': 'j',
  'letters': '\u006A\u24D9\uFF4A\u0135\u01F0\u0249'
}, {
  'base': 'k',
  'letters': '\u006B\u24DA\uFF4B\u1E31\u01E9\u1E33\u0137\u1E35\u0199\u2C6A\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA7A3'
}, {
  'base': 'l',
  'letters': '\u006C\u24DB\uFF4C\u0140\u013A\u013E\u1E37\u1E39\u013C\u1E3D\u1E3B\u017F\u0142\u019A\u026B\u2C61\uA749\uA781\uA747'
}, {
  'base': 'lj',
  'letters': '\u01C9'
}, {
  'base': 'm',
  'letters': '\u006D\u24DC\uFF4D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u0271\u026F'
}, {
  'base': 'n',
  'letters': '\u006E\u24DD\uFF4E\u01F9\u0144\u00F1\u1E45\u0148\u1E47\u0146\u1E4B\u1E49\u019E\u0272\u0149\uA791\uA7A5'
}, {
  'base': 'nj',
  'letters': '\u01CC'
}, {
  'base': 'o',
  'letters': '\u006F\u24DE\uFF4F\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u00F5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u00F6\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u00F8\u01FF\u0254\uA74B\uA74D\u0275'
}, {
  'base': 'oi',
  'letters': '\u01A3'
}, {
  'base': 'ou',
  'letters': '\u0223'
}, {
  'base': 'oo',
  'letters': '\uA74F'
}, {
  'base': 'p',
  'letters': '\u0070\u24DF\uFF50\u1E55\u1E57\u01A5\u1D7D\uA751\uA753\uA755'
}, {
  'base': 'q',
  'letters': '\u0071\u24E0\uFF51\u024B\uA757\uA759'
}, {
  'base': 'r',
  'letters': '\u0072\u24E1\uFF52\u0155\u1E59\u0159\u0211\u0213\u1E5B\u1E5D\u0157\u1E5F\u024D\u027D\uA75B\uA7A7\uA783'
}, {
  'base': 's',
  'letters': '\u0073\u24E2\uFF53\u00DF\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B'
}, {
  'base': 't',
  'letters': '\u0074\u24E3\uFF54\u1E6B\u1E97\u0165\u1E6D\u021B\u0163\u1E71\u1E6F\u0167\u01AD\u0288\u2C66\uA787'
}, {
  'base': 'tz',
  'letters': '\uA729'
}, {
  'base': 'u',
  'letters': '\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289'
}, {
  'base': 'v',
  'letters': '\u0076\u24E5\uFF56\u1E7D\u1E7F\u028B\uA75F\u028C'
}, {
  'base': 'vy',
  'letters': '\uA761'
}, {
  'base': 'w',
  'letters': '\u0077\u24E6\uFF57\u1E81\u1E83\u0175\u1E87\u1E85\u1E98\u1E89\u2C73'
}, {
  'base': 'x',
  'letters': '\u0078\u24E7\uFF58\u1E8B\u1E8D'
}, {
  'base': 'y',
  'letters': '\u0079\u24E8\uFF59\u1EF3\u00FD\u0177\u1EF9\u0233\u1E8F\u00FF\u1EF7\u1E99\u1EF5\u01B4\u024F\u1EFF'
}, {
  'base': 'z',
  'letters': '\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763'
}];

var diacriticsMap = {};
for (var i = 0; i < defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap.length; i++) {
  var letters = defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].letters;
  for (var j = 0; j < letters.length; j++) {
    diacriticsMap[letters[j]] = defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].base;
  }
}

// "what?" version ... http://jsperf.com/diacritics/12
function removeDiacritics(str) {
  return str.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, function(a) {
    return diacriticsMap[a] || a;
  });
}

function removeNonAlphanumeric(str) {
  return str.replace(/[^0-9a-z]/gi, '');
}

function searchOccurences(hay, needle, ignoreCase) {
  needle = removeNonAlphanumeric(removeDiacritics(needle));
  if (ignoreCase) needle = needle.toUpperCase();
  return hay.filter(
    function(word) {
      word = removeNonAlphanumeric(removeDiacritics(word));
      if (ignoreCase) word = word.toUpperCase();
      return word == needle;
    })
}




// Below is the demonstration


var words = "L'avantage d'utiliser le lorem ipsum est bien     évidemment de pouvoir créer des maquettes ou de remplir un site internet de contenus qui présentent un rendu s'approchant un maximum du rendu final. \n Par défaut lorem ipsum ne contient pas d'accent ni de caractères spéciaux contrairement à la langue française qui en contient beaucoup. C'est sur ce critère que nous proposons une solution avec cet outil qui générant du faux-texte lorem ipsum mais avec en plus, des caractères spéciaux tel que les accents ou certains symboles utiles pour la langue française. \n L'utilisation du lorem standard est facile d’utilisation mais lorsque le futur client utilisera votre logiciel il se peut que certains caractères spéciaux ou qu'un accent ne soient pas codés correctement. \n Cette page a pour but donc de pouvoir perdre le moins de temps possible et donc de tester directement si tous les encodages de base de donnée ou des sites sont les bons de plus il permet de récuperer un code css avec le texte formaté !".split(' ');

console.log(searchOccurences(words, "francaise"));
```

Of course the `defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap` may not be complete. To solve this, you need to dive deeper into how Unicode works.

**Alternative Way to remove diacritics**

Unicode has something called normalization forms. To explain with an example, the character `ş` consists of just one char code `351` in NFC (Normalization Form C, Javascript and HTML uses this by default I think). But in NFD, it consists of 2 characters `s` and `Combining Cedilla` represented by char codes `115` and `807`. So, you can just turn your string into NFD and remove any characters out of your defined alphabet range to achieve your goal.

Fortunately for you, EcmaScript 6 introduced a [normalize function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize#Using_normalize()). It is not natively supported in old browsers but I assume it can be [polyfill'ed](https://github.com/walling/unorm). This is how you implement removing diacritics with normalization forms:

```js
function removeNonAlphanumericAndDiacritics(str) {
  return str.normalize("NFD").replace(/[^0-9a-z]/gi, '');
}

function searchOccurences(hay, needle, ignoreCase) {
  needle = removeNonAlphanumericAndDiacritics(needle);
  if (ignoreCase) needle = needle.toUpperCase();
  return hay.filter(
    function(word) {
      word = removeNonAlphanumericAndDiacritics(word);
      if (ignoreCase) word = word.toUpperCase();
      return word == needle;
    })
}


// Below is the demonstration

var words = "L'avantage d'utiliser le lorem ipsum est bien     évidemment de pouvoir créer des maquettes ou de remplir un site internet de contenus qui présentent un rendu s'approchant un maximum du rendu final. \n Par défaut lorem ipsum ne contient pas d'accent ni de caractères spéciaux contrairement à la langue française qui en contient beaucoup. C'est sur ce critère que nous proposons une solution avec cet outil qui générant du faux-texte lorem ipsum mais avec en plus, des caractères spéciaux tel que les accents ou certains symboles utiles pour la langue française. \n L'utilisation du lorem standard est facile d’utilisation mais lorsque le futur client utilisera votre logiciel il se peut que certains caractères spéciaux ou qu'un accent ne soient pas codés correctement. \n Cette page a pour but donc de pouvoir perdre le moins de temps possible et donc de tester directement si tous les encodages de base de donnée ou des sites sont les bons de plus il permet de récuperer un code css avec le texte formaté !".split(' ');

console.log(searchOccurences(words, "francaise", true));
```

Comment: Thanks, I like that. Do you know how to determine whether the `defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap` is *complete*? Is there some kind of Unicode property which says "hey, I'm actually character xyz just with an added diacritic"?

Comment: @D.R. I cannot be sure if it is complete. Thus, I expanded the answer with an alternative way, a better one for sure.

Comment: That sounds like a *sound* idea! Great, I'll give it a try as soon as I can!

Comment: This is some serious stuff here but awesome.  You could never find this level of search in say, the most robust text editor but JavaScript can do it.  Most impressive.

Comment: @GokhanKurt, Now I know this is super over the top but can this be used for regular search words as well.  I have a one off library of quick scripts I saved in autohotkey.  This gem has a place in it but I want to be sure its not too bloated for the task.  Let me know.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon You can use the second one, it is just one line. The first one however is a no go.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need

https://github.com/codebox/homoglyph/blob/master/javascript/src/homoglyph.js

To extend the functionality use this file which is full of homoglyphs
https://github.com/codebox/homoglyph/blob/master/raw_data/chars.txt

I suppose you are using a jquery script for table search. Use the above script to extend the functionality to recognize homoglyphs.

**For handling the punctuations**
If the script is a common plugin it must be looping through the table, matching the words for each cell. When the value(content) of a cell is picked use something like code below to ignore the punctuations of that cell value.

```
s.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"");
```

Then pass the modified cell value and the user entered value to the homoglyph function. Modify the homoglyph function to return true or false instead of matches, and pass the boolean to your current plugin search function, simply denoting whether the cell has matching content or not.

If it is difficult to modify your existing code, see this example, http://www.vijayjoshi.org/examples/filterTable.html 
and extend this with the homoglyph function and ignoring the punctuation.

Comment: Thanks, would like to combine your answer with the one of @GökhanKurt !

Answer (score 2):

Some kind of fuzzy search lib seems to be what you're looking for:

From wikipedia:

> In computer science, approximate string matching (often colloquially referred to as fuzzy string searching) is the technique of finding strings that match a pattern approximately (rather than exactly).

[fusejs.io](https://github.com/krisk/fuse) is an example (first google result)

Comment: I will second this. fuse.js is a pretty good library for this. I created a quick [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hwgh30pe/) you can check out. It does, however include the misspelled `hallo`, so you may want to run this, then filter the results a second time extracting any that don't belong from misspellings.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to implement a normalization function which, for every equivalent string, returns the same result (no matter if it is syntactically correct or not) and use it to compare both strings.

Example:

```
"use strict";

var str_norm = (function(){

    const accents = [
        // First charcter is "master" the rest equivalences.
        // (Add as much equivalences as you need)
        'aàáäâ',
        'eèéëê',
        'iìíïî',
        'oòóöôø',
        'uùúüû',
    ].map(function(p){
        return {
            re: new RegExp('['+p.substring(1)+']', 'g'),
            chr: p.substring(0,1),
        };
    });

    function removeAccents(str) {
        for (var i=0; i<accents.length; i++) {
            str = str.replace(accents[i].re, accents[i].chr);
        };
        return str;
    };

    return function str_norm(str) {

        return removeAccents(str
            .normalize() // Replace "a"+"á" (etc...) UTF-8 sequence by its "a" (etc...) single character equivalence.
            .toLowerCase() // Normalyze to lowercase.
        )
            .replace(/[^a-z0-9\s.,:;ñç]/g, '') // Remove all strange characters.
            .replace(/[\s.,:;]+/g, ' ') // Replace spaces and punctuation (notice: previously accepted) sequences with single space.
        ;


    };
})();


console.log (str_norm("H-éllò  ;- Wø%rld!!")); // hello world
console.log (str_norm("H-éllò  ;- Wø%rld!!") == str_norm("Hello World!!!!!!")); // true
```

For partial matchings, you will need a little more plumbing. For example, to match strings containing provided pattern.

```
var str = "H-éllò  ;- Wø%rld!!";
var searchPattern = "world";
//console.log (str_norm(str) == str_norm(searchPattern)); // (boolean) false
//console.log (str_norm(str).match(str_norm(searchPattern))); // (array with matches) (true value).
console.log (!!str_norm(str).match(str_norm(searchPattern))); // (boolean) true (coerced by "!!").
var searchPattern2 = "foo";
//console.log (str_norm(str).match(str_norm(searchPattern2))); // null (falsy)
console.log (!! str_norm(str).match(str_norm(searchPattern2))); // (boolean) false

// Actual output:
// true
// false
```

...or using typical wilcards too (but this requires a slight change of the normalizing function adding a parameter to instruct it to not remove wilcard characters):

```
"use strict";

var str_norm = (function(){//{{{

    [...] (No changes here)

    return function str_norm(str, acceptWilcards) {

        str = removeAccents(str
            .normalize() // Replace "a"+"á" with "a", etc...
            .toLowerCase() // Normalyze to lowercase.
        )
            .replace(/[^a-z0-9\s.,:;ñç*?]/g, '') // Remove all strange characters.
        ;
        if (! acceptWilcards) str = str.replace(/[*?]/g, ''); // Also remove wilcards.

        str = str.replace(/[\s.,:;]+/g, ' '); // Replace spaces and punctuation sequences with single space.

        return str;

    };
})();//}}}


var str = "H-éllò beautïfull ;- Wø%rld!!";
var searchPattern = "hello*world";

var searchRegex = new RegExp(str_norm(searchPattern, true)
    .replace(/\?/g, '.') 
    .replace(/\*/g, '.*')
);      

console.log (!!str_norm(str).match(searchRegex)); // true
```

> **NOTE:** To be polite, *searchRegex* construction would require to also replace '.' and '*' by '.' and '*', respectively, to escape literal occurrences and using lookbehind in the the other replaces. But, in our case, we are previously filtering it in the normalization function because we doesn't accept it. So we doesn't need to bother about it.