# Javascript irc bot node.js concatenating strings from text file error

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, irc

I am creating an irc bot using node.js and the IRC library (https://github.com/martynsmith/node-irc). When I try to concatenate strings from a text file the irc bot shuts down and throws an error. I suspect there are some invisible line breaks that messes things up, but I don't know how to test it or to get rid of it if that is the case.

**Explanation of the code:**
When a user types in a message in the irc channel, myFunction is called. 
myFunction reads a text file called test.txt and saves the rows as elements in an array called myArray. I then try to make the bot to print out an element of that array, using the bot.say command. config.channels[0] is the channel the message was typed in, and also where the bot should respond.

The bot can print out myArray[0] and myArray[1] on different lines without problems, but it cannot concatenate anything afterwards.

**Error message:**
*C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\irc\lib\irc.js:849
                        throw err;
                        ^
Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ([object Object])
    at Client.emit (events.js:171:17)
    at Client. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\irc\lib\irc.js:643:26)
    at Client.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at iterator (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\irc\lib\irc.js:846:26)
    at Array.forEach ()
    at Socket.handleData (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\irc\lib\irc.js:841:15)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:260:13)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)*

**test.txt** contains the letters a b c d on different lines.

```
var config = {
    channels: ["#channelname"],
    server: "se.quakenet.org",
    botName: "testbot"
};

// Get the lib
var irc = require("irc");

// Create the bot name
var bot = new irc.Client(config.server, config.botName, {
    channels: config.channels
});


// Listen for any message
bot.addListener("message", function(from, to, text, message) {

    myFunction(); //call myFunction when someone types something in the channel

});

function myFunction() {

var myArray = readTextFile('test.txt'); 

bot.say(config.channels[0],myArray[0]); //Print out the first element in myArray (works, this prints out 'a')
bot.say(config.channels[0],myArray[1]); //Print out the second element in myArray(works, this prints out 'b')
bot.say(config.channels[0],'test' + myArray[0]); //Works, prints out 'testa'
bot.say(config.channels[0],myArray[0] + 'test'); //concatenate a string afterwards (prints out 'a' and then throws an error and makes the bot disconnect from server)
bot.say(config.channels[0],myArray[0] + myArray[1]); //prints out 'a' and then throws an error and makes the bot disconnect from server


}

//function to read a text file:   
function readTextFile(file) {
    var fs = require("fs");
    var textFile = fs.readFileSync("./" + file, {"encoding": "utf-8"});
    textFileArray = textFile.split('\n');
return textFileArray;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was some bad invisible characters that came along from the text file (still no idea what characters though). Found the answer in another post, I removed all non-alphanumeric characters from all elements in myArray by using mystring.replace(/\W/g, '').

[Remove not alphanumeric characters from string. Having trouble with the [\] character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364400/remove-not-alphanumeric-characters-from-string-having-trouble-with-the-char)