# How to modify this code to create a dictation app?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code that simply compares **str2** (User input) with **str1** (our reference string ) to check if any word in **str2** is typed wrongly or correctly. The code works fine but I can't find a solution to this problem:

I want to ignore extra spaces, commas and dots and any other writing signs to be compared in both strings. just like a dictation app...

for example, below strings should assume as equal strings on output:

str1 = "I was sent to earth"

str2 = "I was, sent to:         earth."

Any other modifications to improve this code is extremely appreciated.
Please Help...

```
var str1 = "I was sent to earth to protect my cousin";
var str2 = "I waz Sent to earth to protet my cousine";

let a = str1.toLowerCase().split(' ');
let b = str2.toLowerCase().split(' ');
let res1 = b.filter(i => !a.includes(i));
let res2 = a.filter(i => !b.includes(i));
console.log(res1);
console.log(res2);

var str1 = res1.toString();
str1 = str1.replace(/,/g, '\n');

var str2 = res2.toString();
str2 = str2.replace(/,/g, '\n');

var player = GetPlayer();
player.SetVar("wrong_Spell",str1);
player.SetVar("right_Spell",str2);
```

Comment: You can replace the characters that are not letters with an empty string.

Comment: ...like `.replace(/\W+/g, " ").trim().toLowerCase()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove not alphanumeric characters from string. Having trouble with the \[\‌\] character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364400/remove-not-alphanumeric-characters-from-string-having-trouble-with-the-char)

Comment: please create a  full code answer, I'll choose yours as the correct one...

Comment: includes is not the best when you have dupe words like `to`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `match` to extract the words using `\w+`:

```js
function words(s) {
    return s.toLowerCase().match(/\w+/g);
}

var str1 = "I was sent to earth to protect my cousin";
var str2 = "I waz Sent to earth to protet my cousine";

let a = words(str1);
let b = words(str2);
let res1 = b.filter(i => !a.includes(i));
let res2 = a.filter(i => !b.includes(i));
console.log(res1);
console.log(res2);
```