# Remove integers in the beginning of a string in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have text in a table's TD which may start with space or number or multiple spaces. I need to remove all the spaces and numbers until I hit a character. I need to do it in jQuery. I am trying to split the text based on the spaces and remove them. But not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table tr").each(function () {
        var leftText = $(this).find("td.leftLinesTD").text();
        var i = 0;
        leftText.split(" ").every(v => {
            if (v = '') {
              leftText.replace(leftText.split(" ")[i], '');
              i = i + 1;
              return true;
            }
            else { return false; }
        });
     });
```

Comment: You _don't_ need to do it in jQuery. Everything you use for this will likely be plain JavaScript.

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Comment: Note that `replace` returns a result, and you ignore it.

Comment: `if (v = '')` `=` should be `==`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove not alphanumeric characters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364400/remove-not-alphanumeric-characters-from-string)

Comment: One-liner: `$("table tr td.leftLinesTD").text((i, oldText) => oldText.replace(/^[\d\s]+/, ''));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a JavaScript & strings question than it is a jQuery question.

You would benefit from use of a regular expression:

```js
let leftText = $(this).find("td.leftLinesTD").text();
leftText = leftText.replace(/^[\d\s]*/, '');
```

This regular expression says "from the start of the string (`^`), gather zero-or-more (`*`) instances of digits (`\d`) and whitespace (`\s`) and replace the matched substring with an empty string (`''`)".

BTW: use of `var` is discouraged these days.  Use of `let` and `const` are more appropriate.